# Importing latest stock price from Yahoo Finance into Python

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, yahoo-finance

I'm using the following source to import fundamental data:

```
data = si.get_stats_valuation(symbol)
data
```

```
0      Market Cap (intraday) 5  1.69T
1           Enterprise Value 3  1.71T
2                 Trailing P/E  58.08
3                Forward P/E 1  46.08
4  PEG Ratio (5 yr expected) 1   2.49
5            Price/Sales (ttm)   3.86
6             Price/Book (mrq)  14.71
7   Enterprise Value/Revenue 3   3.85
8    Enterprise Value/EBITDA 7  26.31
[0, 1]
```

How do I get the latest price?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this still works:

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si

symbol = 'aapl'
latest_price = si.get_live_price(symbol)
```